# Strange socket behaviour (one computer - my laptop - will accept a connection to my server, another - my PC - won't)

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, python

I wrote 2 programs in Python 2.7. One creates a host socket while the other one creates a client socket. Then they try to connect. I had my host program on my PC and put my client program on my phone that was connected to the WIFI on the same network as my PC. I set the client program(on my phone, which is on my LAN), to connect to local IP address of my PC. I checked for flaws in my code and found out it is flawless. However when I tried to run it, I got some very strange behaviour in return:

1. Port is correct. Hostname is correct. I try to connect. Nothing happens. No connection is established.
2. I reset my PC.
3. I try it again. Same result.
4. I turn off both my local and public firewall.
5. Now i get something, but only on my client device: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
6. I turn my firewalls back on.
7. Same result as in 1. (no connection)
8. I run the host program on my laptop. I try to connect. It works!
9. I reset my router and run my host program on the PC again. Same result as in 1.
10. I now run the client program on my PC as well, connecting it to "localhost". It works.
11. I do the same as in 10. setting the client program to connect to my PCs local IP address again. Error:

    ```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
        s.connect(cn)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
        return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
    error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
    ```

In 6. I came to the conclusion that the problem is related to the PC and that my programs work fine.

Some intels:

- Windows 7 on both PC and laptop.
- I am using Python 2.7.
- Laptop and smartphone are connected into network via WIFI, PC via cabel.
- I tried different ports to make sure they were not the problem.

probably not that relevant but here is the code for the host and client  http://pastebin.com/raw/wswMi5SV

What is going on?

Comment: It may or may not be your code, but your statement "I checked for flaws in my code and found out it is flawless" <-- is a nonsense statement.  You never really know if your code is flawless.. It might lack particular flaws.. but to say it's flawless is nonsense. Maybe some code has  a security flaw due to the platform, so you can't really say it's flawless. You could say there's no flaw that you can determine. And you've chosen not to share the code, because you think it's flawless. Anyhow, your question kind of borderlines SO vs superuser..You may need to do more troubleshooting of some kind

Comment: so your program, when running on a particular computer,  accepts a connection the first time, and fails the second time.  Whereas when running on other computers, always accepts a connection?

Comment: you could try cygwin and nc -l -p 1234  or nc -l 1234, (whichever the nc command is to get a listening server), And try connecting to it, see if it has the same issue as your program. (maybe always do -l -p to be safe, )

Comment: See, what I meant with flawless is that it works on a different computer. It's also how posts on internet say it should be done. If you want to see the code I can show it to you. It is realy simple, a few lines. To answer the second comment: It doesn't work on my PC, but it works on my laptop. The behaviour that is strange is that if I enable the firewall, nothing happens (host is still listening and client still tries to connect), while if disable it, connection gets refused. As for the third comment, I'll try that now and I'll let you know about results.

Comment: i'd like to see the code - i'm curious. Also, check the netstat results(netstat -aon),.. see the IP it is listening on, is it 127.0.0.1 is it e.g. 192.168.x.y(allowing LAN to connect) ,  is it 0.0.0.0(allowing anybody to connect). You can also try wireshark(a packet sniffer), though it may not be any good for testing a connection to 127.0.0.1 but you can connect another computer to the pc and run wireshark on the pc and see what's going on.

Comment: also try "safe mode with networking", on the pc in case some program is blocking it, hopefully that program won't run in safe mode

Comment: I checked netstat -aon for 127.0.0.1 which equals to "localhost" and searched for the port I used: **listening**.

Comment: This can't work. You wrote (round brackets added by me) "I set the client program(on my phone, which is on my LAN), to connect to local IP address of my PC" <---  If by local IP address of your PC, you mean 127.0.0.1  that cannot work from your phone.

Comment: And at step 8 you haven't said where you are connecting from. By the way, saying local IP is ambiguous. State the IP, if it's 192.168.x.y  or 10.0.0.x  or 127..x.y.z

Comment: Your post is really badly written.  You often mention "it" in step 3, and the reader has to look elsewhere in your post to figure out what you are talking about(referring back to prior steps and the beginning paragraph).  Try to make each sentence or at least each paragraph, self contained.  e.g. you say in step 1 that you connect. To find out from where to where one then has to re-read your paragraph above step 1. The writing of your post reads like spaghetti code with gotos.

Comment: You didn't understand me. My client program is connecting to "192.169.1.4", while my host program is hosted on "localhost" which is "127.0.0.1".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39147/discussion-between-barlop-and-cosinux).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  It turned out that the connection was going to the wrong computer.  So, the connection showed that the remote connection was refused, but the problem was on the local computer.

One way to test this is to turn off the network interface on the remote system (or unplug the network cable).  Then, try to connect.  You should get a different error message (WSAETIMEDOUT).  If you still get the WSAECONNREFUSED error, then it is coming from a different device on the network.

In my case, I had two network interfaces on the local computer and one had the same IP address as the remote device.  So, it was trying to connect back to the local computer.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently binding to `localhost` which is an internal interface only. Programs that bind to `127.0.0.1` are not accessible over the network, this is by design. This can be seen when you get a "connection refused" when you connect with the firewall down. When you send a *TCP SYN* to a closed port, the OS will send back a *TCP RST* back to the client to indicate the port is closed.

When you say binding to `0.0.0.0` didn't work can you be more specific? How does it fail exactly?

One thing you can try is this:

```
server.bind(("", port))
```

If I remember correctly, that will attempt to bind to all available interfaces. I'm not sure what you've tried previously but this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But there seems to be a complex problem with my computer. I've done a lot of testing and found out there is a problem with my PC. The problem is probbably somewhere in my PC's settings as I tried a lot of different approaches to getting my programs to work and I didn't solve the problem, while I left out the possibility of anything else being the problem. I found out that connection gets established if I host a server socket on my phone. The problem only occurs with my PC. Program works fine on my laptop.

Comment: I believe that binding to different interfaces won't work. I already tried 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.4.

Comment: Any attempt will result in **connection refused** error. I also tried to connect my phone to computer via cellular network, setting port forwarding to my PC, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the output of a netstat on the laptop and PC with the program running?